# Simplify a log of a log and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, divergent-series

I'm having a bit trouble trying to write this pattern out

if
$$
f_k(x) = 
x \cdot \log(x) \cdot \log(\log(x)) \cdot \ldots \cdot 
\log(\ldots(\log(x))).
$$
where the final term has k logs in it
(So $f_0(x) = x$,
$f_1(x) = x \log(x)$,
$f_2(x) = x \log(x) \log(\log(x))$, and so on).
then how would I write the final term?

Is there a way to simplify writing a log of a log?

Comment: You might consider product notation and notation for the $j$th iterate of a function. Say superscript "powers" that are overlined or underlined to remind you they're function iteration, not exponents. Then something like $f_k(x) = x \prod_{j=1}^k \log^{\overline{j}}(x)$ would do it. I don't think there is a standard notation for function iteration; the product notation is fairly standard. Note that you can't iterate $\log$ forever on positive reals (and stay real) because eventually you get negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

If you want to indicate you're [composing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) a function $n$ times, it's standard to write

$$f^{\circ n}(x).$$

That is

- $f^{\circ 0}(x) = x$
- $f^{\circ 1}(x) = f(x)$
- $f^{\circ 2}(x) = f(f(x))$
- $f^{\circ 3}(x) = f(f(f(x)))$
- etc.

So your term is the product of $\log^{\circ j}$ for $j \leq k$. Or, in symbols:

$$
f_k(x) = \prod_{j = 0}^k \log^{\circ j}(x)
$$

If you aren't familiar with $\prod$ as a product, you can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Product_of_a_sequence).

---

I hope this helps ^_^